# RegExp (JS) - вырезать адрес из смешанной строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста идеи, как из текста, подобного формата

```
"Апт. пункт № 10 Уфа Вологодская, 34", 
"Аптека № 1 Мелеуз 50 лет ВЛКСМ, 19 а", 
"Аптека № 146, Киргиз-Мияки, Губайдуллина, 122", 
"Аптека № 223 Уфа Пр. Октября, 56 а (Спортивная)"
```

вырезать именно адрес ?!

Comment: Данные в одну строк, или как поправил @S.Nick - в несколько?

Comment: Благодарю Вас!) отличное решение !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная логика в разделении строки с помощью [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)-а в методе [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Объяснение `RegExp`-а:

- Выбираем символ `№` с пробелом - `№`
- Далее должно быть число хотябы с одной цифрой - `\d+`
- После числа быть может есть запятая - `,?`
- После всего этого обязательно должен быть пробел -

```js
const buildsWithAdress = [
  'Апт. пункт № 10 Уфа Вологодская, 34', 
  'Аптека № 1 Мелеуз 50 лет ВЛКСМ, 19 а', 
  'Аптека № 146, Киргиз-Мияки, Губайдуллина, 122', 
  'Аптека № 223 Уфа Пр. Октября, 56 а (Спортивная)'
];

const addresses = buildsWithAdress.map(buildWithAdress => buildWithAdress.split(/№ \d+,? /)[1]);

console.log(addresses);
```